# Creating a new array from a subset of a previous array

Tags: c, arrays, element

I have an array of characters like such:

```
    #define SIZE 4096
    char array[SIZE];
    fgets(array, SIZE, stdin);
```

I want to remove any punctuation marks such as (') so that the array elements will be:

d o n t d o t h a t

as opposed to

d o n ' t d o t h a t

How would I go about making a new array that does not include the punctuation characters?

Comment: Copy the characters one by one to the new array and skip the punctuation characters. Don't forget to copy the NUL terminator. It's not that hard...maybe 3-4 lines of code. Be aware that the string read with `fgets` is terminated by a `\n`

Comment: I only have the "don't do that" as an example. I want to be able to do it with all sorts of phrases  e.g. "i can't believe that isn't an option" where I would ignore both apostrophes in "can't" and "isn't".

Comment: My comment still stands, OK maybe a bit more than 4 lines of code, but it's still simple and basic. Where do you have difficulties?

Comment: My bad I misread it on face value. I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the new array avoiding punctuation marks, and add a `null` terminator to the end of the output array:

```
int main() 
{
    char punctuation[] = { '.', '?', '!', ':', ';',
                            '-', '(', ')', '[', ']',
                            ',', '"', '/'};

    char input[SIZE], output[SIZE];
    int i, j, k, ch, flag;

    i = j = k = flag = 0;

    /* get the input string from the user */
    printf("Enter your input string:");
    fgets(input, SIZE, stdin);
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

    /* copy characters other than punctuations */
    while (input[i] != '\0') 
    {
        flag = 0;
        ch = input[i];

        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(punctuation); j++) 
        {
            if (ch == punctuation[j])
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!flag) 
        {
            output[k++] = input[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    output[k] = '\0';

    /* print the resultant string */
    printf("Resultant String: %s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

You can increase/decrease the `punctuation` array size as per your requirements. The default C locale classifies these characters as punctuation:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

There is also a default function, `ispunct`, in C for this:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("All punctuation characters in C"
            " programming are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
        if (ispunct(i) != 0)
            printf("%c ", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `sizeof(punctuation)` rather than `13`. And `4096` has a `#define` already in the asker's code.

Comment: yeah right, thanks for the suggestion. will edit it.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No problem! My pleasure :)

Answer (score -2):

```
#define SIZE 4096
char array[SIZE];

char result[SIZE];
fgets(array, SIZE, stdin);

for(int i=0; array[i]; i++)
{
    char a;
    a = array[i];
    if((a > 0x20) && (a < 0x2f))
        continue;
    else
        result[i] = a;
}

result[i] = '/0';
```

Comment: I think hardcoding ASCII (in hex, no less!) is not okay, and absolutely not clear. Just use `ispunct()`.

Comment: ...and the algorithm is wrong. You need a separate index for `result`. ANd you forgot about other punctuation characters such as `? ` which is not included in `[0x20, 0x2f]`